# Is "as" a conjunction in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The coronavirus pandemic has wreaked havoc on the global jobs market, leaving many unemployed, furloughed or working reduced hours ***as*** employers implemented sweeping cost-cutting measures.

If the "as" is a conjunction in this sentence, does it mean "so"?

Can I rewrite the sentence like The coronavirus pandemic has wreaked havoc on the global jobs market, so employers implemented sweeping cost-cutting measures like leaving many unemployed, furloughed, or working reduced hours.

Comment: No, certainly **not**! It's a preposition that happens to have a clause as complement. It's true that dictionaries say it's a conjunction, but the rule is 'never use dictionaries for grammar'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a conjunction, but it doesn't mean "so", it means "while".

[Cambridge "as" conjunction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)
"during the time that:
*I saw him as I was coming into the building.*
*He gets more attractive as he gets older*."

Many people are being laid off **as** employers cut costs.

Comment: Does “as” mean "because"

Comment: It can, as you will see in the Cambridge definition. Look at the examples they offer for that use; it is different, and I think "while" is the intended sense in this example.